# why vs code syntax highlighting stop working

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

i use vue and vuex. i just realised that the syntax highlighting stops in the middle of the .js file.
what could be the reason for that?

i have the nessessary add on to syntax highlight

[image: syntax highlight stop working]

Comment: It's better if you could provide the code as text instead of as an image.

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: How am i soposed to show the syntax highlight error if i don’t load the image???? ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

its because of Babel JavaScript. i installed a earlyer version and now everything works fine again.